# Grid View With Top, Bottom And Right Side Scroll Bar

Tags: html, css, gridview, webforms, scrollbar

I think I am close to having this all set-up following the jsFiddle I found here:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/1/) however, the issue I run into is that, I do not actually have a scrollbar on the top, and due to setting the height of `div2` the bottom scrollbar is way down on the page.  What needs to be edited in order to have the grid view auto size height wise, and to have the scroll bar at top and bottom?

```
<div class="wrapper1">
<div class="div1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
<div class="div2">
    <asp:GridView ID="returndata" runat="server" Visible="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        ShowFooter="true" Width="1000px" Height="300px" >
        <columns>       
            <asp:BoundField DataField="abcd" HeaderText="J12121212e" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="efg" HeaderText="12112" />       
            <asp:BoundField DataField="hij" HeaderText="2323" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="klm" HeaderText="S" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="nop" HeaderText="C" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qrs" HeaderText="88"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="tuv" HeaderText="8" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="wzr" HeaderText="8888" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="erre" HeaderText="22222" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="aca" HeaderText="1111"/>     
            <asp:BoundField DataField="acsa" HeaderText="222" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ere" HeaderText="3131" />            
            <asp:BoundField DataField="asdf" HeaderText="31" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dasf" HeaderText="33" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qq" HeaderText="3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="xga" HeaderText="21" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="qqqqq" HeaderText="2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="mm" HeaderText="1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="adfasdf" HeaderText="11" />
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</div>
    <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper1, .wrapper2{width: 1000px; border: none 0px RED; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y:hidden;}
    .wrapper1{height: 16px; }
    .wrapper2{height: auto; }
    .div1 {width:1000px; height: 12px; }
    .div2 {width:1000px; height: 600px; overflow: auto;}
</style>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `<asp:BoundField DataField="ere" HeaderText="3131 />`. You did not close the `HeaderText` attribute, i assume that might break your code.

Comment: @Tarekis - that was just a typo.  You are correct that would cause a debug error if application was attempted to run.